# How does the network speed work?

Tags: windows, networking, network-share

I have connected one laptop to my pc via network cable. and I have shared some files between them. and it took 10MBps to share files but I connected another laptop to my PC and It sent 100MBps. so I would like to know why it happen? and how the file sharing speed depending on...? please help me someone to let it know...

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. Your question is not suitable for this site as it's about programming related questions. If you have network or hardware/software related question I would suggest you check out stackexchange instead

Answer (score 0):

10/100 is switchable between 10Mbps and 100Mbps so your rate of connection will be the slowest rate of the client and server. In this case if you are getting 10Mbps from your pc than you probably have a very old network card that isn't 10/100. Consider upgrading!

Comment: 10MBps (megabytes per second) is roughly the same as 100Mbps (megabits per second).  Hard to say which the OP actually means, but it seems reasonably likely that one laptop had a gigabit port and the other only had a 10/100 port.  In any case, laptops usually have ethernet on the motherboard rather than as a separate card, so it probably can't be upgraded.

Comment: Ok, I repaired my answer. Sadly I'm still on 10/100 networking, lol.